# Anaconda installation script won't run

Tags: scripts, python, anaconda

[image: the result of doubled click in .sh file] The red lines are because I pressed b button by mistake.

Comment: obviously , your file was opened in text editor. You should tell filemanager to make open that file as program

Comment: So do I need to close it now??

Comment: How can I run it as a programm?

Comment: You got the file from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), yes? It's 400MB, which is way beyond the size of a shell script. It's probably a compiled program or .deb file.

Comment: I checked over the file. The first ~550 lines are a shell script, then after that it looks to be a compiled program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Anaconda. What is it? Where did you download it from? You may not have gotten what you wanted.

If it's supposed to be a .deb installation file, rename it from .sh to .deb, right-click on the file icon, and see if Archive Manager can open it.

If it's a pure binary file, rename the file from Anaconda_blah_blah_blah.sh to Anaconda, and in the file manager (Nautilus), right click on the file, choose Properties, and under the Permissions tab, check the "Allow executing file as program".

postnote: according to the Anaconda download page, it says to do the following in terminal:

```
bash Anaconda3-4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```